# Change the google marker icon on Geofield module

Tags: views, google-maps

I need to change the default google marker icon on geofield displayed in my view for a custom marker. I tried adding style google map module but it didn't work. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location).

[image]

> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).

[image]

Head over to its (impressive) project page for even more information about it (it would be way too long to include a quote of it all here). That project page also includes various screenshots.

**Note**: Uploading custom markers should be possible also, similar to what you can see in the [screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/custom%20markers.jpg) in the feature request about [Custom markers](https://www.drupal.org/node/1985952).

Comment: Ok, Thanks I will try the module. But this module allow me to upload a custom marker? my client sent me the marker that he wants to

Comment: @Geek Have a look at the **Note** I just added (to the end). Curioous for your feedback after you tried this module.

Comment: I tried but in my preview of the view display this error: The preview function is incompatible with Google Maps so cannot be used. Please visit the page path or block to view your map. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I installed the module, then on my view I added an attachment, under format selected the module.

Comment: I solved the problem and the module work like a charm! thanks! I just need to configure the pop up info window to my custom CSS